# Adding QtCore Library in blackberry 10 sdk

Tags: eclipse, qt, blackberry-10

Hi guys I am creating a simple game using cocos2d-x and blackberry. I need some place to store my game settings, something similar to shared preferences in ios and android. I found some code using qsettings, but the problem is I am not able to add the QtCore library.

I add the library using RightClick->configure->add Library and Standard BlackBerry Platform Library. The library gets added successfully.

```
#include "dataProcessor.h"
#include <QtCore>

void dataProcessor::setup(){
    QDir dir;
    dir.mkpath("data/files/text");
    dir.cd("data/files/text");
}
```

but when I compile the above code, I get the error `C:/Users/I076636/Documents/target_10_0_9_1673/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qatomic.h:45:28: fatal error: QtCore/qglobal.h: No such file or directory`

But I noticed 2 things,
1.qglobal.h file is there inside the QtCore directory I have included.
2.inside qatomic.h if I change

```
#ifndef QATOMIC_H
#define QATOMIC_H

#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
#include <QtCore/qbasicatomic.h>
```

into

```
#ifndef QATOMIC_H
#define QATOMIC_H

#include <qglobal.h>
#include <QtCore/qbasicatomic.h>
```

the error for qglobal goes and now the same error comes for qbasicatomic.h.

I think it is something simple like incorrect mapping between QtCore keyword and include directory or something..

Please do have a look.

The IDE is made on eclipse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can understand what is going wrong if you look closely at the error message:

```
/target_10_0_9_1673/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qatomic.h:45:28:
fatal error: QtCore/qglobal.h: No such file or directory
```

The error isn't in your inclusion of `QtCore`, but is occurring inside `QtCore/qatomic.h`, on line 45 (you can find this file in the `[YOUR BBNDK DIRECTORY]/target_10_0_9_1673/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/qatomic.h`):

```
#include <QtCore/qglobal.h>
```

`qatomic.h` is already in the `QtCore` directory, and you'll find a `qglobal.h` directory there as well. So what this means is that qatomic.h expects the *parent directory* to be on the include path, so that including `<QtCore/qglobal.h>` will work.

So you just need to add `[YOUR BBNDK DIRECTORY]/target_10_0_9_1673/qnx6/usr/include/qt4` to your include directories.

Do it like this:

1. Right click over your project in Project Explorer and choose `Properties`
2. Expand the tree to `C/C++ General` / `Paths and Symbols`
3. Change the Configuration in the Paths and Symbols frame to `[All configurations]`
4. Click the `Includes` tag and select `GNU C` in the Languages list (or do this for every language).
5. Click `Add...` and type `${QNX_TARGET}/usr/include/qt4` and press `OK`
6. Click `Add...` and type `${QNX_TARGET}/usr/include/qt4/QtCore` and press `OK`

Now your include of #include <QtCore> should work.

Next up: linking errors ;-)

Comment: Yeah.. You are right.. Thanks. There was some linking errors. But I fixed it!!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your BB10 NDK did not get installed properly, or your project wasn't set up properly. If you expand your project and the Includes you should see (along with others):

```
<NDK_INSTALL_LOCATION>/target_<VERSION>/qnx6/usr/include/qt4/QtCore
```